# How to test if file ends with }?

Tags: perl

I would like to check is my puppet files (.pp) ends with `}` and with optional  and newlines.

All I care about is the exit code.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a flag. Set it to 1 if a line ends with a } or is empty. After the end of file, retrieve the last flag set:

```
my $ok;
while (<>) {
    if (/}\s*$/) {
        $ok = 1;
    } else {
        undef $ok unless /^\s*$/;
    }
}
die unless $ok;
```

Comment: I don't think so. This code says that any file that ends with a blank line is valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'unless(/^[\s]*$/){$x=$_;}if(eof){if($x=~m/\}[\s]*$/){print "match\n"}}' your_file
```

tested below:

there are some empty newlines at the end of the file and one of those empty newlines has spaces too.

```
> cat temp2
this is key2
this is key1
this is key1
this is key1
this key2 kmkd
}
```

execution:

```
> perl -ne 'unless(/^[\s]*$/){$x=$_;}if(eof){if($x=~m/\}[\s]*$/){print "match\n"}}' temp2
match
```

Comment: This fails because it only checks the current line once the EOF is found.  Because only the last line is checked, newlines cause the program to not find the } before them.

Comment: Also, Choroba, I know you from perlmonks! :D

Comment: @choroba and @protist..corrected the command to handle your cases.`grep . file` will remove all the blank lines from the file and the result will be passed to perl.so now i guess it should be fine.

Comment: @sarathi: Not really. Optional spaces still not handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'undef$/;print"} at end\n"if$_=~/}\s*+$/' FILENAME
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too big, you can do it like this:

```
{
    #Set input record separator to undefined; reads in everything as one line.
    local $/;
    #FILE is a filehandle you have already opened.
    print "Happy ending!" if (<FILE> =~ /}\n*$/s);  
}
```

This method reads the whole file into a single string, making it easy to match what you are looking for with a regex.

(This way is simple, but choroba's approach is better if you have a large file, because it doesn't read the whole thing into memory.)

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work for you. Essentially it keeps a flag that says whether the last non-blank line ended with a brace followed by optional whitespace. It expects the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $valid = 0;

while (<>) {
  $valid = /\}\s*$/ if /\S/;
}

print $valid ? "File is OK\n" : "File is invalid\n";
```